# Sql - find if date is between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field of FromDate and a field of ToDate.

I am looking for the rows that today is between the "from" and "to"

```
      select * from job
      where job.type='manager'
      and '2014-01-22' between job.FromDate and job.ToDate
```

The query does not throw an exception , and it even returns some rows. But it isn't right- the rows it returns do not have the dates I am looking for.

P.S. the date format I am using is the correct one for my DB.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (SHOW CREATE TABLE statement and INSERTS) for the above, and/or an sqlfiddle.

Comment: Please show example data, desired results, and what you are actually getting.

Comment: How do you verify result is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from job
where job.type='manager'
and job.FromDate <= '2014-01-22' and job.ToDate >= '2014-01-22'
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work either. Interesting though- it returns the same list that my query does. Which is the wrong answers.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing dates is often tricky, especially if the values are stored as `datetime` and not `date`.  The time components can affect the comparison.  Another possibility is that `ToDate` is NULL for the most recent records.  Here is one way to fix this:

```
  select *
  from job
  where job.type ='manager' and
        date('2014-01-22') between date(job.FromDate) and date(coalesce(job.ToDate, '2099-12-31'))
```

However, the use of the function on the columns can make the query less efficient.  Instead, you might try:

```
  select *
  from job
  where job.type ='manager' and
        job.FromDate < '2014-01-23' and
        (job.ToDate >= '2014-01-22' or job.ToDate is null);
```

Comment: okay sorry guys for your trouble. I was doing something wrong.